# Google Calendar "widget" within Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

I'm looking for something within Gmail that is similar to that within Yahoo mail.  At the bottom of your mail screen, is your upcoming calendar events.  I know about the Calendar widget, but it doesn't seem to work very well.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

> I know about the Calendar widget, but
>   it doesn't seem to work very well.

Are you referring to the Google Labs "Google Calendar Gadget?" If not, give that one a try. Note that it has a little "options" menu that you can use to enable/disable some features. For instance you can just show upcoming events or a monthly calendar or both.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to that one.  I actually like the placement of Yahoo's better, and the Lab gadget doesn't actually show me any of my upcoming events...

Comment: I can't help you with placement (Haven't used Yahoo in years - no clue where their cal is located) but the calendar gadget definitely shows upcoming events -- I live and die by it! Try "Edit Visible Calendars" under options to make sure you didn't uncheck yours?

Comment: Looks like I have an Invalid token.  Will have to ask a new question related to that :)